# Delete files conditionally

Tags: r

I have a series of csv files in a folder and I want to delete them conditionally. The filename formats are like so :-

```
testfile_2020_05_01.csv
testfile_2020_05_02.csv
testfile_2020_05_03.csv
testfile_2020_05_04.csv
testfile_2020_05_05.csv
testfile_2020_05_06.csv
testfile_2020_05_07.csv
testfile_2020_05_08.csv
testfile_2020_05_09.csv
testfile_2020_05_10.csv
testfile_2020_05_11.csv
```

There are other files in the folder too. I want to delete the above files by specifying the following conditions :-

All files with filename beginning with "testfile" and ending with ".csv" with the length of the filename equal to 23.

Is there a way to do it in R?

I couldn't do it - I tried a lot of things like identifying ending in ".csv" or beginning with "testfile" but don't know how to combine multiple conditions with "list.files" command select these files.

Once I can select these files conditonally, I can then delete them using a loop unless there is a better and faster way of doing so.

Any suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
#Get full path name for all the file
all_files <- list.files('/path/to/files', full.names = TRUE)
#Select conditionally files which start with testfile and end with csv
#and have 23 characters in them
files_to_delete <- all_files[grepl('^testfile.*\\.csv$', basename(all_files)) & 
                             nchar(basename(all_files)) == 23]
#delete the files.
do.call(file.remove, list(files_to_delete))
```

Comment: Ronak <- Thanks. Will try that out and let you know. Do I need the path if they all reside in the working directory?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal No, if they are in working directory you don't need `full.names = TRUE`. Also you'll not need `basename`.

Comment: <- Why would I not need the basename? If the files are in the working directory,then would the "full.names" command only store the filename excluding the path, would it?

Comment: You can try it to understand the difference. If the files are in the working directory and you don't use `full.names` it gives you filename as "testfile_2020_05_01.csv", "testfile_2020_05_03.csv" etc. so no need of `basename`.

Comment: I just did. Here are the outputs for the current working directory (output in part) <- "./20180213.csv" "./aatest.csv" from "list.files(full.names = TRUE)" command and "20180213.csv" "aatest.csv" "aatest.csv" from command basename(list.files(full.names = TRUE))

Comment: OK. Sorry. Got it. Please ignore my previous comments. All good. Works fine! Thanks.